# Helicon Ape: Doesn't work on my Computer IP

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, helicontech

I'm using IIS 7.5 on a Windows 8.

I've got a situation where when I go onto my computer's localhost (`192.168.2.6`) from another computer connected to the same network the URL Rewrite doesn't work, however, when I use `localhost` on my computer it does.

[image: When I connect to <code>192.168.2.6</code> on the host computer.]

Answer (score 0):

this behavior is by design. You don't need license for localhost - developers can test for free.
If you have up to 3 sites, you can use Free version of Ape which has no functional limitations.
Otherwise, you need to purchase Full version.